# Factory reset Google Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: google-play-services, nexus-7

I have factory reset my Google Nexus 7 (2013) tablet. After connecting to the wifi during the setup procedure and selecting either option (copy data from different device / none) it fails with the message '"Google play services" was stopped'.

Is there any chance of recovering this tablet? Do I need to root it and install a custom rom without the Google Play services in order to use it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [Nexus Root Tool](https://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) to unlook the boot loader and update the stock ROM.

Previous build was: RAZOR-FLO: Android 6.0.1 - Build: MOB30M
Updated build was: RAZOR-FLO: Android 6.0.1 - Build: MOB30X

After the update I was able to complete the setup without Google Play Services crashing. The NRT is well documented and I just needed to follow all the messages within the app.